# Log4J2 custom logger

Tags: java, log4j2

In order to perform a JSON logging, I used the properties from Log4J2 (properties="true"):

```
    <rollingFile name="JsonFile" fileName="logs/student-ds-service.json"
                 filePattern="logs/student-ds-service-%d{yyyy-MM-dd}-%i.json.gz">
        <Policies>
            <TimeBasedTriggeringPolicy/>
            <SizeBasedTriggeringPolicy size="100 MB"/>
        </Policies>
        <JsonLayout complete="true" properties="true">
        </JsonLayout>
    </rollingFile>
```

It allows me to do the following:

```
    try (final CloseableThreadContext.Instance ctc = CloseableThreadContext.putAll(map)) {
        logger.info(message);
    }
```

Where "map" is a map of keys and values. It will render like this in the logs:

```
{
  "timeMillis" : 1534426598078,
  "thread" : "http-nio-auto-1-exec-2",
  "level" : "INFO",
  "loggerName" : "be.api.impl.V1ApiImpl",
  "message" : "Get student data by citizenNumber=12345678901",
  "endOfBatch" : false,
  "loggerFqcn" : "org.apache.logging.log4j.spi.AbstractLogger",
  "contextMap" : {
    "citizenNumber" : "12345678901"
  },
  "threadId" : 23,
  "threadPriority" : 5
}
```

My question is I would like to write a custom logger that would do things like this:

```
public void info(String message, Map<String, String> map) {
    try (final CloseableThreadContext.Instance ctc = CloseableThreadContext.putAll(map)) {
        logger.info(message);
    }
}
```

Where "logger" is the log4j2 logger implementation.

What is the cleanest way to do this ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used the generation of extended logger as explained in http://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.0/manual/customloglevels.html#CustomLoggers. The problem is I have to explicitly refer to the logger implementation in the class where I want to log, I wished it was possible just to use the LogManager.getLogger(...) instead.